# Are there single word alternatives that incorporate the "quantitative/ cumulative increase" aspect of the word "upvote"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, synonyms

As per Wiktionary, the definition of "upvote" is the following

To vote for, increasing a cumulative tally of popularity.

Note that the phrase "a cumulative increase" in the above definition emphasizes/ denotes a "quantitive" change.

I was searching for synonyms for upvote and these are the closest alternative words/ phrases -

approve; agree

However, I believe that these words do not indicate a "quantifiable" increase

My question is the following -

Are there single word alternatives that incorporate the "quantitative/ cumulative increase" aspect of the word "upvote"

Answer (score 2):

The closest I can think of (to *verb* form of *upvote*) is ***endorse*** - the higher the number of individuals endorsing something, the higher is its popularity in the target group of people; each individual *endorsement* is equivalent to an *upvote* that way.

ODO:

> **[endorse](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/endorse)** (*US* **indorse**)
>   *VERB*
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>   **1** Declare one's public approval or support of
>
> ‘Some top judges have endorsed our product and this shows that some of
>   the best food in the country comes from just down the road!’